# How to add on hover effect when scrolling past images on a touchscreen (without clicking the images just sliding across them)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The effect I'm talking about cab b le best seen here https://brunofontenelle.design/
You don't hsve to click and scroll, just sliding up the images makes a dim effect

Comment: To get better answers you should add a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: scrolling doesn't seem to change the look for me, only the mouse over does.

Comment: Scroll on the images on mobile phone, the image is dimmed then a narration about that image appears. For example the first image will write 'ivy store logo'